# About the absolute Galois group

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am surprised by the elements of the absolute Galois group. Except for the identity and the conjugation, we can not write other elements explicitly. Also, any automorphism of a Galois extension $K/\Bbb Q$ can be lifted to an element of the absolute Galois group.

But I have ambiguity with these facts: Consider the automorphism $\sigma(a+b\sqrt 3)=a-b\sqrt 3$ of the Galois extension of the field $K:=\Bbb Q (\sqrt 3)$. Lets denote its lift by $\tau$. Can we find an element $\alpha \in \bar{\Bbb Q}\backslash \Bbb Q (\sqrt 3)$, for which we have $\tau(\alpha) \neq \alpha$? The above fact tells us there should be some $\alpha$'s, but I mean can we write it down **explicitly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\sqrt[4]{3}$. If $\tau(\sqrt[4]{3})=\sqrt[4]{3}$, then $\tau(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}$ which is not the case. We actually need to have $\tau(\sqrt[4]{3})=i\sqrt[4]{3}$ or $\tau(\sqrt[4]{3})=-i\sqrt[4]{3}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was quite easy. But I didn't see that. Another irrelevant fact which I've realized right now is: that «I can not accept your answer in the first minutes! The site does not let me do this right now!» I think I have to wait until it passed at least 10 minutes from posting your answer.